# No buttons are working after applying jQuery load() function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I know that no buttons will work after the jQuery load() function is applied. I also know how to solve this. For example, a solution like this:

```js
$("body").on("click", "#btn", function(event) {
  $("body").load(window.location.href);
  alert("page loaded.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

But I use bootstrap and I also use bootstrap's features such as dropdown and modal. I know I can't fix the same button used when doing a dropdown. Because I didn't write bootstrap's javaScript codes. But there must be a solution to this. How can I solve this problem? Can someone help me?

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to provide more information about your specific problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can find a information about jquery load function.
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_load.asp

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.